# How to add static library to dynamic framework in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I have a framework, "MyFramework", written in Swift.
I want to put a static framework Mailcore (.a) into "MyFramework".
How can i do it? I'm using `module.modulemap` but not success.

Comment: I have tried tons of times, Xcode always throw "undefined symbols" errors, did you get any luck?